# image_picker: ^0.7.2+1 makes the app crash

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, camera, imagepicker

i am using image_picker: ^0.7.2+1 [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) in my app

i am using this code for opening the camera

```
     File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

also Added these Permissions in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

**after using above package when my camera is opening immediately the app crashes and in terminal there is no error message it just says device disconnected. (by app crash i mean app restarts (from splash screen )automatically and captured image is also lost)**

this above app crashing issue comes only in android 10 or above android version also in android 10 or above (android 11) also this packages does not asks for the permission of camera in android 10 or 11 which i guess can be the actual problem behind this issue

while i use android 8 or device with android version less then android 10 the image_picker: ^0.7.2+1 [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) works totally fine with same above given code (no changes are made in code just changed the device from android 11 to android 8) the app asks for permission as expected and then camera opens and successfully pic is captured and hence everything works fine nut same thing fails in android 10 or android 11

note : i also tried using permission_handler plugin with image_picker  but it also didn't worked for me

can anyone please help me to fix this issue

also if some one know any substitute code or package for image_picker can please tell me.. i just want to take pic from from camera in flutter

Comment: Have you get the solution, I am also getting the same problem in one of redmi device.Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

I too went through all of this, setting up permission handling, doing the cache fix, and a few other bits I found online, and after a week could not solve it. Image_picker still crashed my app as soon as I took the shot. My solution in the end was to use **camera_camera 2.0.1**. It is a terrible library name, and it doesn't include compression, but the camera interface is nicer, and it works perfectly out of the box.

```
import 'package:camera_camera/camera_camera.dart';

onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => CameraCamera(
                  onFile: (file) {
                    // Do what you like with File file
                    // I convert to base64 ready to upload
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                )))
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as an attribute to the `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml. The attribute is false by default on apps targeting Android Q.

Comment: firstly thanks ..but i have already added this android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the <application> after reading documentation of image_picker but it doesn't work

Comment: any one please suggest some other solution please

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on several devices.
And since I used `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in AndroidManifest.xml **everything works fine for me**..

Answer (score 0):

///// **SOLVED** /////

All you have to do to fix this is add these 6 lines to ios/Runner/Info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to photo library</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to camera to capture photos</string>

<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to microphone</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

After stuck of 2 weeks finding solutions all round, I found my solution to give profile access to my users.
The solution is I used two alternative packages that work well.

For Getting Image Type

```
file_picker 5.2.2
```

For Getting Camera Image

```
camera 0.10.0+4
```

Now,it is working very well.
Also,we need to give kinda to Flutter as it is trying its best though having platform issue in some cases.